# variable trouble in lisp

Tags: variables, lisp, common-lisp

I'm writing a program in Common Lisp in which I need a function with this basic outline:

```
(defun example (initial-state modify mod-list)
  (loop for modification in mod-list
        collecting (funcall modify initial-state modification)))
```

The problem is that I need `initial-state` to be the same every time it is passed to `modify`, but `modify` can be destructive.  I would simply make a copy, but I don't want to make any assumptions about what type of data `initial-state` is.

How can I make this happen?  Or is it even possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the function can be destructive and you cannot do anything about it then it's clear you need to make copies of `initial-state`.

One possibility to avoid preconfiguring what kind of data does `initial-state` contains is to leave providing a copy operation explicitly a problem for the caller or to make it a generic operation and relying on someone else to provide a method.

```
;; Version 1: the caller must provide a function that
;;            returns a new fresh initial state
(defun example (build-initial-state modify mod-list)
  (loop for modification in mod-list
        collecting (funcall modify (funcall build-initial-state) modification)))

;; Version 2: copy-state is a generic function that has been
;;            specialized for the state type
(defun example (initial-state modify mod-list)
  (loop for modification in mod-list
        collecting (funcall modify (copy-state initial-state) modification)))
```

The first version is more general because it allows the state to be any object while in the second version the copy operation depends on state object type (and this means you cannot have two callers both using lists as state with a different copy semantic).
However `copy-state` is a general operation that can be probably used in other places and making the operation a generic increase usability (you don't need to pass around builder functions instead); it also allows the introduction of other generic operations like `compare-state`, `write-state`, `read-state`...